# I want to continuously create radiogroup with radiobuttons programmatically

Tags: android, radio-group

I'm building an app that behaves like a questionaire. the questions comes from a database. the number of questions can be quite a lot (assume unlimited).

Now here's the thing. I manage to build the app to pull 10 questions from the database. once the user has scrolled to the bottom (question 10), the app will pull another 10 questions from the database. the layout will also be extended i.e. the user will be able to view question 1-20. once the user scrolled to the bottom, the app will again pull another 10 questions. i.e. user now can view question 1-30. The layout will be something like this.

question 1.

```
answer A
answer B
answer c
```

question 2.

```
Answer A1
Answer B2

....
```

Question 10.

```
Answer X
Answer Y
Answer Z
Answer XY
```

and so on.
My question is how to create the radiogroups and radiobuttons programmatically.

i.e radiogroup 1 will have 3 radiobuttons (answer a, answer b and answer c). and as you can see. radiogroup 1 will continue to survive in the app until the user ends the usage of the app. if the user scrolled down to e.g question 100. there should be 100 radiogroups.

at the end of all the questions that the user has stopped using, there will be a submit button to send all the user choices.

I'm thinking to user a radiogroup array. e.g.

```
Radiogroup rg[]= Radiogroup[];
```

However, it is not allowed as I have to initialize the size of the radiogroup array.

Comment: I'm using java android studio programming language

Comment: Instead of the array you could use a `List` where you can add elements without worrying about the size.